# Homestead Vagrant Virtualbox cannot resolve DNS inside guest OS

Tags: dns, vagrant, virtualbox, homestead, ubuntu-18.04

My Homestead Vagrant box cannot resolve DNS from within the guest OS, though network traffic otherwise passes through fine.

```
vagrant@homestead:~$ ping google.com
ping: google.com: Temporary failure in name resolution
vagrant@homestead:~$ ping 8.8.8.8
PING 8.8.8.8 (8.8.8.8) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=1 ttl=121 time=23.0 ms
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=2 ttl=121 time=21.9 ms
^C
--- 8.8.8.8 ping statistics ---
2 packets transmitted, 2 received, 0% packet loss, time 1001ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 21.956/22.516/23.077/0.580 ms
```

[Related](https://serverfault.com/a/620198/460947) [questions](https://superuser.com/a/1381145/409879) [have](https://serverfault.com/a/506206/460947) pointed to modifying Virtualbox's `natdnshostresolver1` flag (though I'm told Homestead already enables this); I've updated my Vagrantfile as below, but to no avail:

```
# -*- mode: ruby -*-
# vi: set ft=ruby :

require 'json'
require 'yaml'

VAGRANTFILE_API_VERSION ||= "2"
confDir = $confDir ||= File.expand_path(File.dirname(__FILE__))

homesteadYamlPath = confDir + "/Homestead.yaml"
homesteadJsonPath = confDir + "/Homestead.json"
afterScriptPath = confDir + "/after.sh"
customizationScriptPath = confDir + "/user-customizations.sh"
aliasesPath = confDir + "/aliases"

require File.expand_path(File.dirname(__FILE__) + '/scripts/homestead.rb')

Vagrant.require_version '>= 2.1.0'

Vagrant.configure(VAGRANTFILE_API_VERSION) do |config|

    config.vm.provider :virtualbox do |v|
        v.customize ["modifyvm", :id, "--natdnshostresolver1", "on"]
    end

    if File.exist? aliasesPath then
        config.vm.provision "file", source: aliasesPath, destination: "/tmp/bash_aliases"
        config.vm.provision "shell" do |s|
            s.inline = "awk '{ sub(\"\r$\", \"\"); print }' /tmp/bash_aliases > /home/vagrant/.bash_aliases && chown vagrant:vagrant /home/vagrant/.bash_aliases"
        end
    end

    if File.exist? homesteadYamlPath then
        settings = YAML::load(File.read(homesteadYamlPath))
    elsif File.exist? homesteadJsonPath then
        settings = JSON::parse(File.read(homesteadJsonPath))
    else
        abort "Homestead settings file not found in #{confDir}"
    end

    Homestead.configure(config, settings)

    if File.exist? afterScriptPath then
        config.vm.provision "shell", path: afterScriptPath, privileged: false, keep_color: true
    end

    if File.exist? customizationScriptPath then
        config.vm.provision "shell", path: customizationScriptPath, privileged: false, keep_color: true
    end

    if Vagrant.has_plugin?('vagrant-hostsupdater')
        config.hostsupdater.aliases = settings['sites'].map { |site| site['map'] }
    elsif Vagrant.has_plugin?('vagrant-hostmanager')
        config.hostmanager.enabled = true
        config.hostmanager.manage_host = true
        config.hostmanager.aliases = settings['sites'].map { |site| site['map'] }
    end


end
```

What else could be preventing the VM from resolving DNS?  Or, can I just set nameservers within the box that will persist?

---

EDIT:
For the time being, I can get it to work by *manually* editing `/etc/resolv.conf` and adding nameservers each time I spin it up.  However, `composer` still requires DNS during the startup process, so this is not a fix.

Here's my Homestead.yaml for the curious:

```
---
ip: "127.0.0.1"
memory: 2048
cpus: 1
provider: virtualbox

authorize: ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub

keys:
    - ~/.ssh/id_rsa

folders:
    - map: ~/code
      to: /home/vagrant/code

sites:
    - map: erich.test
      to: /home/vagrant/code/snowman/public

databases:
    - homestead
```

Comment: Sounds like you haven't set the DNS server up on the VM. Normally that is done using DHCP. Try `dig google.com @8.8.8.8`. if that works you just need to edit the resolv.conf file

Comment: i am currently doing just that, each time i load the vm.  how do i persist that change?    
 and even so, this is not an optimal solution -- not having dns also affects `vagrant up` since composer needs dns as well.

Comment: it seems that vagrant on windows has more problems than it's worth, especially with `npm` in the mix.

Comment: @erich Out of curiosity, have you tried using `--natdnsproxy1` instead of `--natdnshostresolver1`? The proxy mechanism is a bit simpler (it just forwards the requests), so if there's something else causing issues with the the guest machine accessing the host DNS APIs it could possibly work around that.

Comment: @erich Also, are either of those flags set in `Homestead.yaml`?

Comment: @justbeez yes i have tried `--natdnsproxy1` as well.  Homestead.yaml is as vanilla as you can get; neither flag is set there.

Comment: @Aron can you recommend a resource to explain why DHCP has to be enabled for the VM to get a DNS server? Those seem unrelated to me (I'm admittedly weak on networking).

Answer (score -2, accepted):

I gave up on figuring out this problem with Homestead/Vagrant long ago.

Instead, I recommend trying out the new [Laravel Sail](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/sail) package (Laravel 8.x+) which uses Docker.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this with that line

```
 sudo ufw allow out 53,113,123/udp
```